# Linking Project To Robotlegs Files In FDT

Tags: installation, swc, fdt, robotlegs

I am trying HelloFlash in FDT - [from the demo bundle](https://github.com/robotlegs/robotlegs-demos-Bundle).

I have robotlegs v1.5.2 as a linked resource from: D:\as3-robotlegs\robotlegs-framework-v1.5.2\src

The robotlegs files are not seeing each other, even though they have the correct package structure - for example you can't control-click to link to the parent class or variables.

Having said that, FDT shows some of the files within the Robotlegs source code as having errors (e.g. Actor.as has no import statements). Maybe that's why I'm having trouble.

What am I missing?

I also prefer to use the code rather than the swc so that I can step through it.

Answer (score 0):

### FDT Can't Parse The Files

> The robotlegs files are not seeing each other...FDT shows some of the files within the Robotlegs source code as having errors (e.g. Actor.as has no import statements)....

If your source files have errors in them, FDT will not be able to parse them and add them to the project model - giving the impression that FDT cannot 'see' them.

While you can still probably still compile ( the errors that FDT shows are only a prediction of compile errors, not a guarantee ) you should go through and fix the errors (such as adding the import statement). By default, FDT has very strict error checking and it's suggested that it be used.

### Attach Your Source Code To The SWC

> I also prefer to use the code rather than the swc so that I can step through it.

You should always use a SWC. When using a library, there is no reason to NOT use a SWC (exactly why is beyond the scope of this answer, but it mostly has to do with performance and memory).

If you want to be able to have Debug features (e.g. setting through the call stack) of the library, then you should attach the source code to the .SWC.

[Learn how to attach source code to a SWC here](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/Source_Attachment_For_SWCs).

It will look like this:

[image]